# Output a chart (png) in Ninja Form depending on submit

Tags: html, forms, charts, ninja-forms

I am searching for the best way to generate a chart depending of the answers in my forms (wordpress - Ninja forms plugin) that could be linked automatically within the HTML mail send by the plugin on submission.
I was thinking about chart.js but I have no idea on how to do that. And perhaps it is not a good solution though.
If someone could help me or has already done that...it would be great.
Thanks you.